# Convert UIBezierPath to MKPolygon?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, uibezierpath, mkpolygon

How can one convert a UIBezierPath to a MKPolygon?

Background:  I wish to create an overlay for an map (MKMapKit) that includes shapes with components of a circle (i.e. arc).  I see that I can create a path that includes circle arcs in the Core Graphics area using UIBezierPath, so is it possible to do this and then covert this path to a MKPolygon and use it for an overlay in the MKMapKit world?

Comment: Did you found a way how to do it?

Comment: no I didn't :( sorry